# how to add property for ListField on mongoengine

Tags: django, mongoengine

I use mongoengine, and love it very.
now I work it with django, and I get a problem with it
how to set property for ListField
e.g.
this was my model

```
class Bussiness(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField())
```

and I want to use it on template like this:

```
{% for tag on bussiness.tags %}
    {{ tag.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

but the `tag.url` I don't want to save it to database, just hope to **produce it on model level**, and make tags only some string on database.
And if I hard code it on template, I have to write it everywhere, that was I disgust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wont work as tag is just a string (you have it defined as a `StringField`).

You could have tag as an embedded document with url being a property eg:

```
class Tag(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()

    @property
    def url(self):
        return "http://my-ace-site.come/businesses/%s/"

class Business(Document):
    tags = ListField(StringField())
```